# Android ActionBar styling issues

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to have custom background for the menu items displayed in the `ActionBar`. I found out that I can do that by adding the following item to my app theme style definition:

```
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/actionbar_button</item>
```

Where `actionbar_button.xml` contains:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/action_btn_on" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/action_btn_off" />
</selector>
```

However, this causes the background image to also render behind the custom app logo displayed on the left of the ActionBar. After several attempts at figuring out a selector that would include only the buttons, I came up with this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/action_btn_on" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/action_btn_off" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Which sort of worked, and after the app loads fully the background behind the logo is transparent as I want it. But the problem is that while it's still loading it briefly shows the logo with the button background behind it and more annoyingly, it *scales and crops the logo* to fit inside the fill area of the 9-patch graphic that is the button background. When finished loading, the background is switched out, but the scaling and cropping remains, which looks quite ugly. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Have not found a working solution to the general problem of setting image-based backgrounds to ActionBar buttons, but the scaling/cropping does not happen if I use entered XML based backgrounds, such as created with a `layer-list` of shapes. For some cases in may not be viable, but in my case it was entirely possible, and maybe even better than using a bitmap based resource.